# Can I sabotage the Cure of the Genophage?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 2 I helped Mordin destroy the genophage's in order to prevent a cure.

Now I find it weird that I am forced by a primary mission to find a cure for the genophage. Is it possible to not deploy or sabotage the cure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sabotage the cure in ME3, if you have high enough PA/RE ranking in that way Mordin lives, you can also sabotage it by killing Mordin at the end and you can do it without high PA/Re ranking.

Comment: It seems I didn't had a high enough Paragon-Rating. Poor Mordin. I had my own "In the Pale Moonlight"-moment there.